# Is there a way to generate pydoc for nested functions?

Tags: python, documentation, pydoc

I'm looking for a way to generate documentation, pydoc on this case, for nested functions. Is this possible with pydoc? Is it possible with other tools?

For example:

```
"""
Module docstring.
"""

def foo(x):
    """
    Foo does something.
    """
    ...

    def bar(y):
        """
        Bar does something
        """
        ...
```

Generating pydoc with: pydoc -w -filename- will generate pydoc for the module and foo() but not for bar().

Normally this would be ok; the problem is that I'm trying to build a library for educational purposes, and documenting what happens inside the closure is specially helpful. I want to find a way to document it without having to expose the inner functions to the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

There is always the manual method:

```
"""
Module docstring.
"""

def foo(x):
    """
    Foo does something.
    N.B. Foo includes a local function bar() that does what bar does.
    """
    ...

    def bar(y):
        """
        Bar does something
        """
        ...
```

It is not automatic but it does mean that your students only get to see documentation on those private methods that you wish them to see.